# Get value of input, only after select option change has happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<"select'>`, with some options and onChange listerner. When an option is selected certain values are set in some hidden fields. So if this change event won't happen, it means the values of those fields will remain in their initial state i.e 0.

What I want to achieve is that, only when an onchange has happened, that means hidden fields values has been set, I get the values from those hidden fields and perform some ajax with the data

This is what I have so far:

```
    <select class="form-control choosedegree" name="sem" id="semester">
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select Semester</option>
        <option value="1">Year 1, Semester 1</option>
        <option value="2">Year 1, Semester 2</option>
        <option value="3">Year 2, Semester 1</option>               
    </select>
```

After this has fired, and finished,

```
$('select#semester').on('change', function(){});
```

then find some hidden input and set the new value gotten as a result of the `onChange`.

```
$('div.tab-content div.tab-pane.active form').find('input[type=hidden]').val()
```

How can i achieve that! Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this:

```
$('select#semester').on('change', function(){

if($(this).val() != "")
{

// send ajax call here
 setTimeout(SendAjaxCall,3000); // execute SendAjaxCall after 3 secs
    }

});


function SendAjaxCall()
{
var val = $('div.tab-content div.tab-pane.active form').find('input[type=hidden]').val();
}
```

Comment: My explaination is just part of a bigger picture, to get the new values from hidden field , onchange must have occured

Comment: @Yunus the code above is, as described, a function bound to fire when the `change` event occurs, so technically it does what you're asking for. Maybe the hidden input changes are also bound to the same event and fire beforehand — in this case putting the function inside a `setTimeout( theFunction(){ … }, 0 )` would solve the problem by allowing all other bound events to execute first

Comment: @Ehsan I'm writing this on my phone so it's difficult for me to write code — maybe you can edit your answer to include the `setTimout`?